# How to discover IP address of all devices on multi segment network?

Tags: c#, snmp, router, segment, subnet

With a 2 segment network for example: 10.20.x.x and 192.168.x.x (255.255.255.0).

How can i find all devices **IP Address** that's support SNMP v1,v2,v3 using C# ?

I tried to use [sharpsnmplib](http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/) discovery sample , but it's only able to find devices of the segment that computer is conected to.

[image]

Comment: Read [faq] and [ask], please..

Answer (score 1):

Try querying the switches (if possible) - do you know the network topology?  Could you just get away with sending out a bunch of pings (and are you OK if some devices don't respond)?

Broadcasting is not possible without broadcast management routers.  The IP routing system is designed to prevent broadcasts from traveling to other network subnets - you must manually set up networks to communicate with one another in broadcast form (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address)

One example of where this limitation exists and is overcome is in the BACnet/IP protocol.  BACnet uses a "Who-Is" broadcast request to solicit attached devices to transmit "I-Am" responses.  Because the broadcasts can't traverse subnets, BACnet uses special routers called BBMDs (BACnet Broadcast Management Device).  To read a little bit more about that, see this [link](http://www.bacnet.org/Bibliography/ES-7-99/IPPART2.HTM).

Comment: First of all thank you for your help,but unfortunately i don't know the network topology i need a generic solution, and i cannot ping range of addresses because ping will fail for another segments and probably will take allot of time too. Enabling broadcast is not an option ether because it's bad thing to do.I thought i can some how use SNMP to send broadcasts to each segment ,but i cannot find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A broadcast only works for 1 segment unless you have routers forwarding the broadcast.

Comment: But the routers often don't forward broadcast to other segments, is there another way to do it without broadcast?

Comment: I don't think so if you don't have the IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

There are two commonly used approaches:

1. Let the user define the IP address range and then do SNMP GET to every address in that range.
2. Start with the arp cache on your local machine, use SNMP to poll every IP address found in the ARP cache and then look at the RFC-1213 MIB atTable (OID  .1.3.6.1.2.1.3.1) for yet undiscovered IP addresses. This should discover every actively communicating network node.

The first approach is much slower in case of large network range with small amount of hosts. The second approach may miss some hosts that do not communicate with gateway.